# Question about the role of the department chair during the faculty hiring process

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I want to better understand the role of the department chair (at an R1 US institution) with regards to the faculty hiring process. I'm sure this differs between departments, but how does the department chair interact with both the search committee, the college, and the interviewee throughout the hiring process?

Comment: That’s a pretty complicated thing to ask about. See [here](https://academicaffairs.ucdavis.edu/academic-duties#FacultyRecruitmentSelAp) for one university’s official answer, which doesn’t even cover a lot of aspects of what happens in practice.

Comment: This will depend on the chair, the department, and can even vary between individual searches...